# Call a method and pass a variable to another controller

Tags: objective-c, variables, methods, controller

I am new in xcode and I have a very basic question. I have been searching for days to find out why my code is not working. I want to pass a variable from one Viewcontroller to another controller.

This is my Viewcontroller:

```
//
//  GameViewController.m
//  Cartas
//
//  Created by Pedro Lopes on 10/5/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Pedro Lopes. All rights reserved.
//

#import "GameViewController.h"
#import "Baralho.h"

@interface GameViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,strong) Baralho *card;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *flipLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cartasRestantes;
@property (nonatomic) int flipsCount;
@property int contador;

@end

@implementation GameViewController

- (Baralho *)card
{
    if (_card == nil)
        _card = [[Baralho alloc] init];
    return _card;
}


- (IBAction)flipCard:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (!sender.selected)
    {
       NSString *temp1 = [[self card] matchCard:@"Just a Test"];

       NSString *temp2 = self.card.drawRandomCard;
       [sender setTitle:temp2 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
       self.cartasRestantes.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cartas Restantes: %@",temp1]; 
    }
    sender.selected = !sender.isSelected;
    self.flipsCount++;
    self.flipLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flips: %d",self.flipsCount];
}

@end
```

This is my other Controller

```
//
//  Baralho.m
//  Cartas
//
//  Created by Pedro Lopes on 10/6/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Pedro Lopes. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Baralho.h"

@interface Baralho()
@end

@implementation Baralho

- (NSString *)matchCard:(NSString *)teste
{
    _matchCard = teste;
    return _matchCard;
}


@end
```

The problem occurs in the line:

```
NSString *temp1 = [[self card] matchCard:@"Just a Test"];
```

The error is:
**!No Visible interface for 'Baralho' declares the selector 'matchcard'**

How do I do to pass the variable to this another controller?

thanks,

Pedro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that Barahlo.h declares:

```
- (NSString *)matchCard:(NSString *)teste;
```